# Missing xmlNode(s) in Google Feed API response when defined: output=json_xml

Tags: json, api, google-api, feed, google-feed-api

According to [Google's Developer's Guide](http://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide#resultMixed), if you define the URL-Argument `"&output=json_xml"`, every entry in the json-result should contain an additional `xmlNode` property, but they don't show up!

Did this get changed or what am I missing/doing wrong?

Example: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&output=json_xml&q=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds`

If you put the result into JSONLint for validation and formatting, you can see there are no XMLNode properties within the `json-part`.

Comment: I know it's an old one, but any chance you've got a solution?

Comment: @Asaf, unfortunately not. Also didn't track this issue longer-term.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually moved to the Google feed library for JS instead of using the API.